# Layering character animations

Tags: animation

Is there a way I can combine animations into a bigger action for a scene?

For example:

I have a breathing animation I created in action editor.  I want this to be played in the "background" no matter what other actions my character is doing at the time.  So far for the videos I've seen, the tutorials have been just creating an entire scene in action editor.  Am I wrong to use the action editor is for creation of single actions to be combined into bigger actions like the one I stated above?

My goal is to make a character with a main action, and sub actions ( breathing ) playing in the background.

I have a feeling the NLA editor is how I do this but I don't know it that well.  Also animation nodes would be perfect for this job but not good at it.  I only know dopesheet.  :(

And Thanks all.

Comment: Yes NLA ... Just change blending mode from Replace to Combine or Add should work https://youtu.be/mfdufhaiKtI

Comment: Can the NLA combine animations to make new animations?  For example an attack animation combined with my breathing animation to form a new one?  I can't save them like I do in action editor no?

Comment: That is what you asked and I said Yes and video nicely presents I think :) Is there any specific issue you deal with? Please edit your question. NLA data are saved as any other part of file, but if you area asking if it is possible to "merge" all actions in one action ...you can search for Bake Actions (with cursor above NLA editor), but it generates keyframes at specific steps, means hard to edit later.